# boost asio stateful socket interface

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I want a Stateful communication but not like boost's echo server example. My socket will be ready for reading forever and whenever it receives a new data it will call a virtual method `dataAvailable(string)` however it can do `async_write` anytime.

```
void connected(const boost::system::error_code &ec) {
  _socket.async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(_buffer, max_length),
      boost::bind(&Session::handler_read, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error,
      boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
  //boost::asio::async_read(_socket, boost::asio::buffer(_buffer, max_length),
  //    boost::bind(&Session::handler_read, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error,
  //    boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
  std::cout << ">> Session::connected()" << std::endl;
}

void handler_read(const boost::system::error_code &ec, size_t bytes_transferred) {
  if(ec) {
    std::cout << ec.message() << std::endl;
  } else {
    //std::copy(_buffer, _buffer+bytes_transferred, data.begin());
    std::string data(_buffer, _buffer+bytes_transferred);
    std::cout << ">> Session[ " << id() << "]" << "::handler_read(): " <<
            bytes_transferred << " " <<  data << std::endl;
    boost::asio::async_write(_socket, boost::asio::buffer(_buffer, max_length),
            boost::bind(&Session::handler_write, this,
            boost::asio::placeholders::error));
    _socket.async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(_buffer, max_length),
            boost::bind(&Session::handler_read, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error,
            boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
    //boost::asio::async_read(_socket, boost::asio::buffer(_buffer, max_length),
        //    boost::bind(&Session::handler_read, this,
        //    boost::asio::placeholders::error,
        //    boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
      //call dataAvailable(_buffer);
  }
}

void handler_write(const boost::system::error_code &ec) {
  if(ec) {
    std::cout << ec.message() << std::endl;
  } else {
    _socket.async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(_buffer, max_length),
            boost::bind(&Session::handler_read, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error,
            boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
    //boost::asio::async_read(_socket, boost::asio::buffer(_buffer, max_length),
        //    boost::bind(&Session::handler_read, this,
        //    boost::asio::placeholders::error,
        //    boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
  }
}
```

1. Is this Implementation Okay ? as multiple threads may do read and write operations. where in write operation is updation of some cells in matrix
2. Why it doesn't work (doesn't echo's the received string) when I use `async_read` instead of `async_read_some`
3. In my listening Server I am nowhere calling the `listen` method. but still its working. Then Why there is a listen method ? and when it is used ?
4. I want to get the notification when the client socket is exited from Client side. e.g. Client has closed connection. How can I do it ? I way comming out is by reading an `End Of File` in `read_handler` But is that the only Way ?
5. I've a Session class, and each session have one socket. I am storing `Session*` colection in a Session Manager. now when I close a socket and `delete` it that session becomes null. and it may happen in the middle of a `vector`. So How to safely remove that `null` session ?

Comment: Can you edit your question with a [self contained reproducer](http://sscce.org/) so we can see how it does not work? There is nothing obviously wrong in the code snippet you have posted.

Answer (score 0):

There is one serious issue with your code. Imagine that you have asymmetric network link and are able to receive much faster than send.

1. Receive message
2. Do async_write (but it takes time)
3. Schedule next read
4. Receive next message
5. Do second async_write (the first one is not completed yet, you get garbage one other side of link)
6. Schedule next read
7. First async_write finishes and schedules one more async_read_some

To sum up, you request asio to do multiple reads and writes to the same socket at once.

> Why it doesn't work (doesn't echo's the received string) when I use async_read instead of async_read_some

Are you sending enough data (`max_length`)? Maybe you would like to use `boost::asio::transfer_at_least(min_length)`?

> In my listening Server I am nowhere calling the listen method. but still its working. Then Why there is a listen method ? and when it is used ?

You probably create acceptor object somewhere.

> I want to get the notification when the client socket is exited from Client side. e.g. Client has closed connection. How can I do it ? I way comming out is by reading an End Of File in read_handler But is that the only Way ?

You could create wrapper, which will take `EOF` and do some cleanup. Then you wrap all your custom handlers with wrapper and pass wrapper as a handler to boost::asio. This way you have only one place to handle EOF error, if you prefer to.

> I've a Session class, and each session have one socket. I am storing Session* colection in a Session Manager. now when I close a socket and delete it that session becomes null. and it may happen in the middle of a vector. So How to safely remove that null session ?

Use `boost::shared_ptr` in handlers and so on and `boost::shared_ptr` or `boost::weak_ptr` in Session Manager's vector.